# Fantasy comic where someone gets smothered by a thorny vine plant late 70s early 80s

Tags: story-identification, comics, sword-and-sorcery

Trying to find a story, or the comic magazine it appeared in. I read it in a childhood friend's garage around 1980-82 but given our ages (about 7) it was probably his father's from a few years previous. I'm in the UK. It left a strong visual impression on me as a kid and despite extensive searching I've not been able to find it.

It was a fantasy story featuring a pair of characters (one male one female?)  escaping through a dark forest, one of the characters is then smothered/eaten by a tree with vines and thorns.

Comic was definitely on the 'mature' end. Visually the drawing was similar to Druillet; detailed/grim/jagged. Other parts of the story featured warriors/knights with spiky armour (think Elric/Warhammer Chaos Warriors) lots of black ink. Comic was magazine format black and white throughout but also had adverts. I've looked through Heavy Metal, Epic Illustrated, much of Warren Publishing's fantasy mags and just can't find it. Maybe someone here can help.

EDIT* I've seen a link in a blog: https://darkworldsquarterly.gwthomas.org/sword-sorcery-at-warren-part-10-1980/ and in a further link I think I may have found the magazine/comic I read, Voltar, "Voltar goes to the Thorn Forest with a goblin named Minorca. This is the entrance of the Goblin underworld. Terrible vines kill the goblin and capture Voltar." Timeline is about right (1980) and the images look about right but I'd need to try and find a copy of issue 3 to be sure.

Comment: Was the person being smothered/eaten rescued or were they indeed killed?

Comment: They were killed. I remember it resembled a huge tangled thorny Bramble bush.